# unable to enter time in a time controller by using selenium webdriver

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation, browser-automation

HTML Code:

```
<mat-form-field _ngcontent-c18="" class="mat-input-container mat-form-field ng-tns-c7-23 mat-form-field-type-mat-input mat-form-field-can-float mat-form-field-should-float mat-primary ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid"><div class="mat-input-wrapper mat-form-field-wrapper"><div class="mat-input-flex mat-form-field-flex"><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "0"
}--><div class="mat-input-infix mat-form-field-infix">
              <input _ngcontent-c18="" class="mat-input-element mat-form-field-autofill-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid" formcontrolname="scheduleFromTimeControl" id="startTime" matinput="" placeholder="Start Time" type="time" ng-reflect-name="scheduleFromTimeControl" ng-reflect-id="startTime" ng-reflect-placeholder="Start Time" ng-reflect-type="time" aria-invalid="false">
            <span class="mat-input-placeholder-wrapper mat-form-field-placeholder-wrapper"><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><label class="mat-input-placeholder mat-form-field-placeholder ng-tns-c7-23 ng-star-inserted" for="startTime" aria-owns="startTime">Start Time <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}--></label></span></div><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "0"
}--></div><div class="mat-input-underline mat-form-field-underline"><span class="mat-input-ripple mat-form-field-ripple"></span></div><div class="mat-input-subscript-wrapper mat-form-field-subscript-wrapper" ng-reflect-ng-switch="hint"><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "error"
}--><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "hint"
}--><div class="mat-input-hint-wrapper mat-form-field-hint-wrapper ng-tns-c7-23 ng-trigger ng-trigger-transitionMessages ng-star-inserted"><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": ""
}--><div class="mat-input-hint-spacer mat-form-field-hint-spacer"></div></div></div></div></mat-form-field>
```

I am unable to enter time in time controller by using .sendKeys

I have used the following combinations with .SendKeys Method:

```
WebDriverUtils.getWebDriver().findElement(By.id(starttime)).sendKeys("Keyss" +Keys.TAB);
WebDriverUtils.getWebDriver().findElement(By.id(starttime)).sendKeys("12:01 AM");
WebDriverUtils.getWebDriver().findElement(By.id(starttime)).sendKeys("1201 AM");
WebDriverUtils.getWebDriver().findElement(By.id(starttime)).sendKeys("10");
```

Inspect element looks as follows:

```
<input _ngcontent-c18="" class="mat-input-element mat-form-field-autofill-control ng-invalid ng-dirty ng-touched" formcontrolname="scheduleFromTimeControl" id="startTime" matinput="" placeholder="Start Time" ng-reflect-name="scheduleFromTimeControl" ng-reflect-id="startTime" ng-reflect-placeholder="Start Time" ng-reflect-type="time" aria-invalid="true" ng-reflect-model="" type="time">
```

Please not i am able to select the start time, but unable to enter time... please find the control snapshot
[image: snapshot]

Comment: Is that input the actual input you need? Can you share the html?

Comment: @marcel i have attached html

Answer (score 0):

i got the solution, the format which i have used was not correct. the correct format is as follows:

```
    WebDriverUtils.getWebDriver().findElement(By.id(starttime)).sendKeys("10:10");
```